# What is the type of the variables in chainCPS?

Tags: haskell, types, continuation-passing

I am looking at the [continuation passing style tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style) and cannot understand the types in the following function.

```
  chainCPS :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> ((b -> r) -> r)) -> ((b -> r) -> r)
  chainCPS s f k = s z where 
    -- z :: (a -> r) -> a -> ((b -> r) -> r) -- Fails
    z x = f x k
```

The above is the remodel of the following:

```
  chainCPS :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> ((b -> r) -> r)) -> ((b -> r) -> r)
  chainCPS s f = \k -> s $ \x -> f x $ k
```

Looking at the type info provided by the Atom editor I can see that `s :: (a -> r) -> r`, `f :: a -> (b -> r) -> r`, `k :: b -> r`. Futhermore in `z` the `x` is of type `x :: a`.

What is confusing to me about this is that `z` is of type `z :: a -> r`.

That means that `s z` should be of type `r` after applying `z` to `s`.

If so, how does the final type come out to `(b -> r) -> r`?

Edit: The `b -> r` comes from `k`...right. That means `z` really is of type `a -> r`, as the editor says. But then why does the following fail typechecking?

```
  chainCPS :: ((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> ((b -> r) -> r)) -> (b -> r) -> r
  chainCPS s f k = s z where
    z :: a -> r
    z x = f x k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That means that `s z` should be of type `r` after applying `z` to `s`.

Nope. It is true that `z someArg` is of type `r`, when `someArg` is of type `a`, but here we are applying `s`, not `z`.

Here instead we have

```
s :: (a -> r) -> r
z :: (a -> r)
```

so `z` matches the type of the argument of `s`. Hence, the resulting type is the result of `(a -> r) -> r`, which is `r`.

Comment: I guess I got my terminology mixed up. Though, why does the above give a type error when I write out the type of `z` explicitly as `z :: a -> r` as in the above?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Because of an arguably wrong default interpretation rule of that signature. Briefly put, Haskell assumes each signature is independent from others, so your `a` in `z :: a -> r` is unrelated to the `a` in the signature of `chainCPS`.  You can tell Haskell that they are indeed the same thing if you write `chainCPS :: forall a b r .  ...` and enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#lexically-scoped-type-variables